Idiomatic Clojure way of mimicking Perl's pack/unpack function
In Perl, pack and unpack are two functions for transforming binary data according to a user-defined template.
Here is a tutorial on these functions:
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut#The-Basic-Principle
What is the idiomatic Clojure way of doing the same things these two functions do?

No reason to bring perl into this -- there are plenty of other implementations of the same thing (f/e Python's struct module), and knowing perl doesn't help anyone answer the question so I'd toss the tag; the perl tag should only be used for questions about perl, as opposed to places where a facility provided by perl is tangentially useful as background/context.

That said, I'd generally expect Java equivalent to Python struct.pack to be on-point; even if there's a native-Clojure frontend, that's likely to be what it backends into.

nippy (https://github.com/taoensso/nippy) is a library that is very useful for converting clojure data efficiently to and from byte arrays... great for network serialization, storage, etc... --- separately, if, for example for ffi interop, a C ABI layout is desirable, you might want to look into dtype-next (https://github.com/cnuernber/dtype-next)

Removed the perl tag from this question as per comments

It probably wouldn't hurt to clarify what you mean by "the same thing". There've been some suggestions made in comments, but the question isn't clear enough about acceptance criteria right now to know which if any could be made into a proper answer. (To raise some questions by way of demonstrating the point: Is the string-based template form something you'd consider critical? If so, is it important that it be a template, or that it be a string specifically?).

It is uncommon for people to invent their own serialization format in Clojure. Instead the most common solutions will serialize existing datastructures to text/binary and back.
The built-in version into Clojure is the EDN format, which is a subset of clojure itself.
(pr-str {:foo "bar"}) gives you "{:foo \"bar\"}". clojure.edn/read-string for that string gives you back the original map.
If you'd prefer a little more compact and slightly more performant variant then transit is a good choice. Same principle as EDN as it has full built-in support for all CLJ datastructures and can be extended for custom types.
If you'd rather really want to use your own custom binary format, you could fall back to using java.io.DataOutputStream and DataInputStream respectively. Of course there are also a lot of libraries that would simplify/abstract this further.
